# Why would an Alias Template be treated differently than the aliased type template when it comes to friendship?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, friend

We observed a surprising behaviour in our code base, where a friendship relation was failing to be applied. (It is currently compiled only with Clang, version 3.6)

We could reduce it to this minimal example. Let's imagine we have the following template class definitions:

```
template <int>
class Element
{};


// Forward declaration of FriendBis
template <template <int> class> class FriendBis;

class Details
{
    friend class FriendBis<Element>;
    int mValue = 41;
};

template <template <int> class>
class FriendBis
{
public:
    void useDetails(const Details &aDetails)
    {
        aDetails.mValue;
    }
};
```

Here, `Details` declares that the instantiation of `FriendBis` with its single template template parameter substituted with `Element` is its `friend`. Because of that, the following client code compiles successfully:

```
FriendBis<Element> fb1;
fb1.useDetails(Details());
```

### The problem

Now, let's introduce the additional `trait` templated type, whose whole purpose is to define `proto` as a template alias for the `Element` template:

```
struct trait
{
    template <int N>
    using proto = Element<N>;
};
```

The client code below does not compile:

```
FriendBis<trait::proto> fb2;
fb2.useDetails(Details());
```

---

It is surprising to us, because `trait::proto` is an alias for `Element`, but one compiles while the other does not.

- Is this an expected behaviour ?

  - If so, what is the rationale for this restriction ?
  - Is there a workaround ? (while maintaining a restricted friendship, instead of making all instantiations of `FriendBis` a friend).

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30654483/4326278. Maybe the details in there will help.

Answer (score 2):

An alias template is not synonymous with the type it aliases: `trait::proto` and `Element` are disparate types. When a template-id refers to the specialization of `trait::proto` *then* it is equivalent to the substituted type. Simply put, `trait::proto` is not `Element`, but `trait::proto<0>` *is* `Element<0>`.

In response to your questions:

- Yes, this is expected behaviour
- The rationale is that the aliased type could be far more complex than just `Element<N>`, it could be something like `Element<ElementForInt<N+1>::value>`. The mapping then is non-obvious.
- I can't think of a workaround off the top of my head. If you want to check if a template template parameter is the same as some other template *and* account for alias templates, you can check if instantiations of the two name the same type, e.g. `std::is_same<T<0>, Element<0>>`, but I'm not sure how you would make that work in a friend declaration.

Comment: This is [CWG 1286](http://wg21.link/CWG1286). Also, `trait::proto` and `Element` are not types.

Comment: Thank you for answering ! I am failing to understand the example you are giving for the rationale. Could you please elaborate a bit regarding why it is then non-obvious ? @TC Thank you for the link.